# Custom PircBot / TwitchBot Profanity Filter

Tags: java, irc, twitch

I'm fiddling around with the Java Pircbot 1.5.0 library and have successfully connected to the twitch chat irc and can send and respond to messages such as !time returning the current time. My bot's twitch account is a moderator on my channel and can do everything you would normally expect that I have tested for (ops, bans etc...)

What I'm now trying to do is replace existing messages so that I can build a simple profanity filter/ banned words filter.

effectively turning this (banned word is frogs):

```
queekusme: I like frogs
```

into:

```
queekusme: I like *****
```

however I can't find anything that would allow me to replace the existing message so that the word is removed.

I know this is possible as bots i have used in the past have been able to do this it's just that I can't find out how to do it on this thing called google.

Comment: Do you know how PircBot works? It doesn't edit messages, it sends them. Unless you can edit IRC messages as they're sent, your bot won't be able to, thanks to the way that PircBot works. You either need a server-side plugin or to be content with filtering only on your end, neither of which uses an IRC bot. You can, however, warn people when they curse, but that's not your question.

Comment: So as the server is on twitch's end, it may not be possible by using pircbot. that's at least a good thing to know.

Comment: That's correct. If you'd like, I can put that into an answer and elaborate a little more.

Comment: FWIW, I think Twitch directly supports custom profanity filters as part of a channel's settings.

Answer (score 0):

I found twitch has in built filters however I found what I was looking for, I need to send a timeout command, this then does the  in chat

PRIVMSG #[channel] :.timeout [UserToTimeOut] [TimeToTimeOut]

for reference